# SSH not logging properly

Tags: linux, debian, ssh, logs

I am looking at `/var/log/auth.log` on a Debian Webserver, and the last thing it logged was:

```
Jul  2 21:09:01 h311 /USR/SBIN/CRON[25912]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime ] && [ -d /var/lib/php5 ] && find /var/lib/php5/ -depth -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -ignore_readdir_race -cmin +$(/usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime) ! -execdir fuser -s {} 2>/dev/null \; -delete)
Jul  2 21:12:37 h311 systemd[1]: Reloading.
```

`/var/log/syslog` has is 0 bytes in size. Older logs are in their archives.

I have tried deleting it, restarting services. It got created again, 0 bytes in size, again.

I have tried to install things like syslog-ng on this server, and deleted them after some playing around. Some package I've installed could have tampered with the configuration, but I can't tell you exactly.

There is also more then one superuser on this server, so it might be something else.

What should I check and try to do in order to get logging working again?

Comment: Do you have any daemon running to handle syslog? `sudo fuser /dev/log` should list a process ID, which is the daemon.

Comment: @wurtel Output is: 
`/dev/log:                1   205`

Comment: Ah, I now see `systemd` in your log output. Systemd thinks it's much better to log everything in binary format, so you need tools to extract the logs from systemd so you can read them; apparently the configuration changed on July 2nd. Sorry, I can't help you with systemd (which I consider evil IMHO. See http://boycottsystemd.org/ , I won't engage in discussions about systemd.)

Comment: 1 = systemd
205 = systemd-journal

Comment: @wrutel I understand, thanks for the help. Could you maybe give me a hint on how to revert back to a Debian native style logging? Turn off systemd?

Comment: systemd is not so easy to turn off; perhaps installing the sysvinit-core package will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As indicated in the comments, your system is using systemd for service management. Systemd is a replacement for the traditional SysVinit. It also bundles in a lot of other things such as a syslog collector. In this case, to get access to your logs, you need to use the `journalctl` command.

```
$ journalctl
```

If you want to see only the `sshd` logs, you can pass a filter:

```
$ journalctl -n 1 _COMM=sshd
-- Logs begin at Wed 2014-10-22 19:29:29 EDT, end at Fri 2014-10-24 09:05:09 EDT. --
Oct 24 09:05:09 gadget sshd[5800]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user phemmer
```

You can see what the available filter fields are by changing the output format to `verbose`:

```
$ journalctl -n 1 -o verbose
Fri 2014-10-24 09:05:09.533633 EDT [s=30566909a26443ffb7185d318ccc4cd6;i=3d5d;b=19dd64e325fd4577a78af1a73f005b6c;m=1e82168a3c;t=5062ad4a511bc;x=1fae374af8a7dbc3]
    PRIORITY=6
    _UID=0
    _GID=0
    _BOOT_ID=19dd64e325fd4577a78af1a73f005b6c
    _MACHINE_ID=5288dcb47f9fed3ab946f54754305a4f
    _HOSTNAME=gadget
    _CAP_EFFECTIVE=1fffffffff
    _TRANSPORT=syslog
    SYSLOG_FACILITY=10
    SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER=sshd
    _COMM=sshd
    _EXE=/usr/sbin/sshd
    _SYSTEMD_OWNER_UID=1000
    _SYSTEMD_SLICE=user-1000.slice
    _PID=5800
    _CMDLINE=sshd: phemmer [priv]   
    _SYSTEMD_CGROUP=/user.slice/user-1000.slice/session-3.scope
    _SYSTEMD_SESSION=3
    _SYSTEMD_UNIT=session-3.scope
    MESSAGE=pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user phemmer
    _SOURCE_REALTIME_TIMESTAMP=1414155909533633
```

---

To answer your comment about disabling systemd. I would not advise it. Your distribution is moving towards systemd, and ripping out a core component of the system will likely make your life extremely difficult.
It would be possible to disable just the log journal, and use a traditional syslog daemon, without too much pain, but I would recommend learning to use the journal before deciding not to use it. Going against convention should not be done lightly.

Comment: Or just query journal only for unit ssh:
`journalctl -u ssh.service`